# An unbiased and consistent estimator

Tags: self-study, econometrics

An unbiased and consistent estimator is said to be efficient if it has?
a. minimum
variance
b. maximum variance 
c. both a and b 
d. none of these

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is self-study, I will give you a hint. Think about which would be preferred - a high variance estimator or a low variance estimator? A high variance estimator would give very different estimate with a new sample whereas a low variance estimator would give you a similar estimate with a new sample.